# Problem in Receiving Audio from Flask socket

Tags: javascript, python, flask, flask-socketio

I am trying to get the microphone audio from the client side and  convert it to Numpy array.
The problem is, I can not convert the incoming audio to Numpy array. When I want to save it as wav file, the resulting file is silent or garbage audio.

Here is the client side:

```
const startStreaming = () => {
        if (!streaming) {
            navigator.mediaDevices
                .getUserMedia({ audio: true })
                .then((stream) => {
                    setCurrentStream(stream);
                    mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
                    mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = (e) => {
                        if (e.data.size > 0) {
                            // Convert Blob data to Float32Array
                            e.data.arrayBuffer().then((buffer) => {
                                const adjustedLength = Math.floor(buffer.byteLength / 4) * 4;
                                const float32Array = new Float32Array(buffer.slice(0, adjustedLength));
                                socket.emit("audioChunk", float32Array);
                            });
                        }
                    };
                    mediaRecorder.start(2000); // 2-second chunks
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    console.error('Error accessing microphone:', error);
                });
            setStreaming(true);
        }
    };
```

Here is the receiver side:

```
@socketio.on("audioChunk")
def onAudioChunk(audio_chunk):
    global chunk_counter

    sendResponseToClient("An audio chunk received in transcription service")

    audio_np = np.frombuffer(audio_chunk, dtype=np.float32)

    sample_rate = 44100  
    wav_filename = 'output.wav'

    # Save the numpy array as a WAV file
    wavfile.write(wav_filename, sample_rate, audio_np.astype(np.int16))
```

I have been trying to solve the problem for days and I appreciate any help.